# How can I split this string (log line) by multiple different characters/patterns?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing, logparser

I have a string like this:

```
66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] "GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I'm having an enormous issue parsing this thing.  I basically just need the ip address, date, "GET" method, response code (404, in this line), and the rest of it as a longer string.  The result should be a comma-delimited list like:

```
['66.249.69.97', '24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000', '"GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1"','404','"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"']
```

It's okay if the solution doesn't return exactly that but I've been trying for hours to parse this and have no idea how to do it.

I've tried `split()` and `strip()` in loops, and am about to try regex...which I'd have to review/relearn.  Any easier ways that I'm just overlooking?

I'm using a python2 notebook so no Python3 options.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:
@arun now I have this:

```
    p = re.compile(r'(?P<ip_addr>\d+(\.\d+){3}) - - \[(?P<date_time>.+?)\] (?P<http_method>\".+?\") (?P<return_code>\d+) \d+ "-" (?P<client>\".+?\")')
    def pattern_match(line):
          m = p.search(line)
          return([m.group('ip_addr'), m.group('date_time'), m.group('http_method'), m.group('return_code'), m.group('client')])
```

I then use this function in:

```
    for line in rdd.collect():
        line = pattern_match(line)
        print(line)
```

`rdd.collect()` is 5 lines of text and when I iterate a print job through it, it prints all 5.  However, I now only get 4 printed this way...and then it errors out with: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] "GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"'''
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?P<ip_addr>\d+(\.\d+){3}) - - \[(?P<date_time>.+?)\] (?P<http_method>\".+?\") (?P<return_code>\d+) \d+ "-" (?P<client>\".+?\")')
>>> m = p.search(s)
>>> [m.group('ip_addr'), m.group('date_time'), m.group('http_method'), m.group('return_code'), m.group('client')]
['66.249.69.97', '24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000', '"GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1"', '404', '"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"']
```

Note that the regex is making some assumptions here and might not work for all your cases, but it should get you started.

(It will be well worth your time learning [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). Hopefully this gets you started :-).)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is supposed to be  the way to go, but there are other things you could try to do as alternatives, like the following:

```
temp1 = '66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] "GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"'.split("\"")
temp2 = temp1[0].split("-")
print [temp2[0].strip(), temp2[-1].strip(" []")] + [i.strip() for i in temp1[1:] if i not in "- "]
```

It's not perfect and maybe a little bit ugly, but to be honest I like it more than regular expressions, as I find it much easier to read.

Comment: It works fine for me. What kind of error do you get?